# Installing Laravel using Composer through PhpStorm

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php, phpstorm

I have checked out many examples of this but for some reason, either I am missing an assumed step or I'm just doing it wrong.

So I am having issues getting Laravel installed locally. I have a `composer.json` and .phar file.

I have ran `php composer install` which downloaded the dependencies. However, this is where it gets different. Seems at this point all the examples I have found are magically working. However in mine, I have a vendor directory with all the dependencies but nothing is actually installed. I have the Laravel source but its not ready for development yet.

Does this make sense? Am I over complicating things?

I am now getting an error:

> Script php artisan optimize handling the post-update-cmd event returned with error code 1

which after checking, that method is there...

**My composer.json:**

```
{
"name": "laravel/laravel",
"description": "The Laravel Framework.",
"keywords": ["framework", "laravel"],
"license": "MIT",
"type": "project",
"require": {
  "php": ">=5.6.4",
  "laravel/framework": "5.4.*",
  "laravel/tinker": "~1.0",
  "barryvdh/laravel-cors": "^0.8.2"
},
"require-dev": {
  "fzaninotto/faker": "~1.4",
  "mockery/mockery": "0.9.*",
  "phpunit/phpunit": "~5.7"
},
"autoload": {
  "psr-4": {
    "App\\": "app/"
  }
},
"autoload-dev": {
  "psr-4": {
    "Tests\\": "tests/"
  }
},
"scripts": {
  "post-root-package-install": [
    "php -r \"file_exists('.env') || copy('.env.example', '.env');\""
  ],
  "post-create-project-cmd": [
    "php artisan key:generate"
  ],
  "post-install-cmd": [
    "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postInstall",
    "php artisan optimize"
  ],
  "post-update-cmd": [
    "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postUpdate",
    "php artisan optimize"
  ]
},
"config": {
  "preferred-install": "dist"
}
```

}

Comment: what do you mean by **I have a vendor directory with all the dependencies but nothing is actually installed** ?? Anything you install using composer goes into vendor directory

Comment: right, so how do i get laravel setup properly?  i have /vendor/laravel/framework/ and then some stuff in there.  This isn't where you do development at.  Isn't there a step somewhere that does things with these dependencies?

Comment: You should have
The app Directory,
The bootstrap Directory,
The config Directory,
The database Directory,
The public Directory,
The resources Directory,
The routes Directory,
The storage Directory,
The tests Directory and the
The vendor Directory. In your root

Comment: If composer downloaded all the dependencies properly then your project is set up. just hit `http://localhost/your_project_folder/public`. and you do not do any development in vendor folder. And please go through the docs

Comment: I have went through the docs.  That is how i ended up here.  I do not have the app directory or bootstrap or routes... all the good stuff is missing.  All i have in my root is the vendor directory with the dependencies downloaded from composer.  outside of that in root, i have composer.phar, composer.lock and composer.json.

Comment: what's in your composer.json?

Comment: composer.json has been added to the original post

Comment: Have you tried this: composer create-project laravel/laravel blog

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like you may have downloaded Laravel itself instead of creating a Laravel project.

The [Installing Laravel](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4#installing-laravel) section of the documentation shows two ways to create a Laravel project:

> ### Via Laravel Installer
>
> First, download the Laravel installer using Composer:
>
> ```
> composer global require "laravel/installer"
> ```
>
> Make sure to place the `$HOME/.composer/vendor/bin` directory (or the equivalent directory for your OS) in your `$PATH` so the `laravel` executable can be located by your system.
>
> Once installed, the `laravel new` command will create a fresh Laravel installation in the directory you specify. For instance, `laravel new blog` will create a directory named `blog` containing a fresh Laravel installation with all of Laravel's dependencies already installed:
>
> ```
> laravel new blog
> ```
>
> ### Via Composer Create-Project
>
> Alternatively, you may also install Laravel by issuing the Composer `create-project` command in your terminal:
>
> ```
> composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel blog
> ```

After doing either of these your project directory should include the proper Laravel directories with all dependencies properly set up.